# Is it possible to remove the "default" WHERE rule for an ActiveRecord relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

#### Short version:

Is there a way to "unscope" ActiveRecord `belongs_to` (or other) associations in Rails 5.0?

---

#### Longer version:

I'm working on a Rails project where each "Job" is assigned to a "Department" for organisation purposes. In most cases the department can be inferred automatically, based on the Job details, but there are a few instances where a Job must be manually assigned to a different Department.

To address this, I've added a `department_id` column to the Job table, with the intention of having things work as follows:

- If `department_id` is not NULL, join the Job to the Department as per usual.
- Otherwise, fall back to the "inferred" Job/Department join logic.

According to the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-belongs-to), this is possible:

> There may be times when you wish to customize the query used by
>   belongs_to. Such customizations can be achieved via a scope block. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> class Book < ApplicationRecord
>   belongs_to :author, -> { where active: true },
>                         dependent: :destroy
> end
> ```
>
> You can use any of the standard querying methods inside the scope
>   block.

As such, I tried defining a relationship as follows (simplified for demonstration purposes):

```
belongs_to :department, -> { unscoped.where(id: 7) }
```

...the idea being that `.unscoped` would remove the default `where departments.id = [jobs.department_id]` logic, allowing me to define a custom rule instead.

However, this doesn't actually un-scope it; the generated SQL is:

```
SELECT  `departments`.*
FROM `departments`
WHERE `departments`.`id` = 11 AND `departments`.`id` = 7
LIMIT 1
```

My guess is that the default WHERE logic is applied *after* the custom-query block is executed, meaning that `.unscoped` doesn't have any effect.

---

#### A few other things:

- I know that I could simply set the `department_id` to the "expected" value whenever a new Job is created. However, this would have a couple of drawbacks:

  - I'd need to retroactively set the `department_id` of every existing Job in the database (which could take a fair amount of time).
  - If a specific type of job were re-assigned to a different "default" department, any existing jobs would remain assigned to the "previous" department.
  - Similarly, if the details of a job were to be updated such that it fell under the purview of a different department, the user would need to manually re-assign it.
- I know that I could define a method - or a custom scope - on the Job model instead of using `belongs_to` here, but for the purposes of this question let's say that I absolutely have to do this via an ActiveRecord relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this a little backwards.  If you have a department_id, let rails be rails and the department method should return it.  Then also have

```
def assumed_department
  return department || guessed_department
end

def guessed_department
  <your logic for guessing>
end
```

If you have a bunch of code that already uses 'department' like I am using assumed_department then you will want to remove department_id and add assigned_department_id

```
belongs_to assigned_department, class: 'Department' # check the belongs_to docs
```

then your `department` method instead returns `assigned_department || guessed_department`
    etc...

But mostly if you have a relationship then you should let your database be a database and add the relationship and always assign it.

Comment: See the last part of my question: _"I know that I could define a method - or a custom scope - on the Job model instead of using belongs_to here, but for the purposes of this question let's say that I absolutely have to do this via an ActiveRecord relation."_

Comment: Additionally, regarding the _"add the relationship and always assign it."_ - please see the reasons stated in the original post for why I would not want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You're fighting the framework and the database pretty hard.

> I'd need to retroactively set the department_id of every existing Job
>   in the database (which could take a fair amount of time).

Yup.  Do it.

> If a specific type of job were re-assigned to a different "default"
>   department, any existing jobs would remain assigned to the "previous"
>   department.

Then maybe you want a has and belongs to many table in between - job_category or some such.  Then you could change what job it points to and everything that referenced it would be updated.

> Similarly, if the details of a job were to be updated such that it
>   fell under the purview of a different department, the user would need
>   to manually re-assign it.

Yeah - so add a before/after callback that sees the criteria was updated and then assigns the appropriate job/category.

Comment: Your two answers make me think that you're misunderstanding what I'm asking. My question was **"Is there a way to "unscope" ActiveRecord `belongs_to` (or other) associations in Rails 5.0?"** (with the Job/Department bit included to provide some context for why I might want to do this), not "how do I implement this specific scenario in Rails?".

Comment: Yes: https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+metaprogramming

What you're asking is "Can I make rails not behave like rails".  Entirely possible.  You might want to look at some of the other ORM backends for rails - mongoid or the like.  See how they hack the ORM to do what they want - though that may still be too strictly relational for what you want to do.  
All my advice has been how to use the framework to do what you want.  None of my advice will be how to fight the framework to make it do what you want the way you  want.